# Converting an expression to conjunctive normal form with a twist

Tags: expression, conjunctive-normal-form

I've got a library that I have to interface with which acts basically as a data source. When retrieving data, I can pass special "filter expressions" to that library, which later get translated to SQL WHERE part. These expressions are pretty limited. They must be in conjunctive normal form. Like:

```
(A or B or C) and (D or E or F) and ...
```

This of course isn't very comfortable for programming. So I want to make a little wrapper which can parse arbitrary expressions and translate them to this normal form. Like:

```
(A and (B or C) and D) or E
```

would get translated to something like:

```
(A or E) and (B or C or E) and (D or E)
```

I can parse an expression to a tree with the [Irony](http://www.codeplex.com/irony) library. Now I need to normalize it, but I don't know how... Oh, also, here's the twist:

- The final expression may not contain the **NOT** operator. However, I can inverse the individual terms by replacing the operators with the inverse operators. So, this is OK:
  `(not A or not B) AND (not C or not D)`
  but this is not:
  `not (A or B) and not (C or D)`
- I would like to make the expression as simple as possible, because it will be translated to a practically identical SQL WHERE statement, so a complex statement would most likely slow down execution speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use two iterations over the tree, although it's probably possible in one.

First iteration: get rid of your NOT Nodes by walking through the tree and using De Morgan's law ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) and remove double negation wherever applicable.

Second iteration (the NOT are now only directly before a leaf node)
Go through your tree:

```
Case "AND NODE":
    fine, inspect the children
Case "OR NODE":
    if there is a child which is neither a Leaf nor a NOT node
        apply the distributive law.
        start from parent of current node again
    else
        fine, inspect children
```

After that you should be done.

Comment: Heh, I had almost arrived there myself. :)