# Boolean Expression Optimization For All AND Conditions

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, boolean-expression, tree-traversal, boolean-operations

I am trying to solve the boolean expression optimization problem for a simple rule engine.

Here is what I am trying to do, lets say if I have following 5 conditions (where a,b,c,d,e,f are complex boolean expressions)

```
if (a AND b AND c AND d AND e AND f) then do-1 
if (a AND b AND c AND d AND e) then do-2 
if (a AND b AND c AND d) then do-3
if (a AND b AND c) then do-4
if (a AND b) then do-5
```

In case when I execute these conditions in a linear order I will

```
- evaluate "a" for 5 times
- evaluate "b" for 5 times
- evaluate "c" for 4 times
- evaluate "d" for 3 times
- evaluate "e" for 2 times
- evaluate "f" for 1 time
```

I would like to make a expression execution tree from this so that each expression (a,b,c,d,e,f) is evaluated minimum number of times. 
The perfect solution will be that each expression is evaluated only once. I think this can be achieved with a tree creation where all these conditions are part of a tree.

The tree may look like this

```
if(a AND b) then do-5  {
    if(c) then do-4 {
        if(d) then do-3 {
            if(e) then do-2 {
                if(f) then do-1 
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

**My questions is -** How can I make this tree from the set of boolean expressions listed above?

*Related Questions:*

[Algorithm for evaluating nested logical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752813/algorithm-for-evaluating-nested-logical-expression)

[Converting an expression to conjunctive normal form with a twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876825/converting-an-expression-to-conjunctive-normal-form-with-a-twist)

[Is it useful in C# to apply DeMorgan's theorem to manually optimize boolean expressions in conditional statements (e.g. if conditions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981830/is-it-useful-in-c-sharp-to-apply-demorgans-theorem-to-manually-optimize-boolean?rq=1)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @tmr232 - thanks for your response. Sorry I am in different timezone so late response. I have updated the questions.

Comment: If your five `if` statements above are source code (as opposed to coming out of a database, or something), it seems you can just do `bool atemp = a; bool btemp = b;`, and so on, and then just refer to those temps in the `if` statements.

Comment: This is more of a switch-case than a tree. I assume you have a list of all the booleans. If so, I would use `list_of_bools.index(False)` to get the correct case, then use a function table to jump to the correct code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, it seems I am not able to describe my problem clearly. Let me think of a better way to describe.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it this way:

```
var booleans = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
var i = 0;
while(booleans[i]) i++;

switch(i) {
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to merge the while loop with the switch operator to get something even more optimized from this.